# Can't run JavaScript in my PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

So I'm trying to run some JavaScript code using PHP by echoing it. The issues I'm having is that it's just printing the JavaScript code onto the webpage instead of running it. The file itself is a PHP file. Here is a snippet of my code that is causing me issues:

```
<?php 

                $file = file('locations.csv');
                foreach($file as $k)
                    $csv[] = explode(',', $k);


                echo '

                <script>
                var map, heatmap;

                    // Initialize and add the map
                    function initMap() {
                    // The location of Uluru
                    var uluru = {lat: -27.469644, lng: 153.025245};

                    // The map, centered at Uluru
                    map = new google.maps.Map(

                      document.getElementById(\'map\'), {zoom: 16, center: uluru});
                    // The marker, positioned at Uluru
                    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
                    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                      data: getPoints(),
                      map: map
                    });

                    }


                    function toggleHeatmap() {
                        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
                    }
                    function changeGradient() {
                    var gradient = [
                      \'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)\',
                      \'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)\'
                    ]
                        heatmap.set(\'gradient\', heatmap.get(\'gradient\') ? null : gradient);
                    }
                    function changeRadius() {
                        heatmap.set(\'radius\', heatmap.get(\'radius\') ? null : 20);
                    }

                    function changeOpacity() {
                        heatmap.set(\'opacity\', heatmap.get(\'opacity\') ? null : 0.2);
                    }

                    function getPoints() {
                        return [



                new google.maps.LatLng('.$csv[1][0].', '.$csv[1][1].'),

                new google.maps.LatLng(-27.469628, 153.025231),
                ];
                }
                </script>

                ';

                ?>
```

Here is what it outputs:

[image: Code Screenshot]

I'm at a loss here, no idea whats causing the issues.

Comment: try adding the `type` : `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Try echoing something simpler.  Does `echo '<script>alert("hey")</script>';` work?

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: ill give that a go @Jonathan

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth it just prints:  " alert("hey")'; echo ' '; ?>  " into the webpage

Comment: So, the script tags are missing completely?

Comment: Yea the script tags dont show up at all

Comment: Is there more code in the file?  I think there's something else going on.

Comment: Thats the only php in the file, the rest is just html and a bit of js

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Turns out it was because I was running the file directly and not through the XAMPP server.  Im a moron, Sorry about the wast of time guys! and thankyou for all of the suggestions

Comment: That would do it.